# Error extracting a substring using IndexOf method ?

Tags: c#, string

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace DownloadImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string f;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string localFilename = @"d:\localpath\";

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#",localFilename + "test.html");
                }

                f = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "test.html");
                test();
        }

        private void test()
        {
            List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;

            string startTag = "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx";
            string endTag = "cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa";    
            startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag);

            while (startIndex > 0)
            {

                endIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag,startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string t = f.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                imagesUrls.Add(t);    
                position = endIndex + endTag.Length;    
                startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag,position);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The List in the end contain 63 indexes.
The first one for example,index 0 contains:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309151800&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
```

Index 5 for example,contains:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309160600&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
```

The last index is the problem,it contains the string i want like in the other indexes but it also contains the rest of the file content from this last index:

This is part of the last index:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&cultuur=thumbnail&continent=europa" border="0"/></a></li><li style="margin-top: -12px;text-align: center;"><a href="/?ir=true&co=true&li=false" target="_top" class="white"><div
```

But the last index should be only:

```
http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&cultuur=thumbnail&continent=europa
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: the last index contains "cultuur=thumbnail" and NOT "cultuur=en-GB"

Comment: How about using some REGEX or HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: AgentFire i don't realy know yet how to use it. Tried htmlagilitypack before but not quite understand it.

Comment: For this specific case i added to my code: string item = imagesUrls[imagesUrls.Count - 1];
            imagesUrls.Remove(item);  that solve the problem since i didn't need the last index. But that's not a real solution since there might be other cases that i will need the last index.

Comment: AngentFire could you show me how to use Htmlagilitypack step by step with comments what each line do ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this cool tool:

### [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/htmlagilitypack)

Some info:

- [StackOverflow: How to use HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).
- [BlogSpot.ru tutorial (extracting links from HTML page)](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.ru/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html).
- [Other useful stuff](http://www.google.com/search?q=htmlagilitypack+tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

for scraping web page, htmlagilitypack is quite useful. Here is a helpful example with explanations:
http://codingfields.com/guides/htmlagilitypack/

This page explains few keys:
http://www.codeproblem.com/articles/languages/81-net-framework/74-html-parsing-in-c-using-html-agility-pack

This page is not bad, too:
http://beletsky.net/2010/09/crawling-web-sites-with-htmlagilitypack.html

This example illustrates replacing context: http://sparkingnaz.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/how-to-use-html-agility-pack-parsing-html-documents-with-the-html-agility-pack-to-extract-content-node-and-replace-content/